# С++ странный вывод(полиморфизм, массивы)

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, полиморфизм

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    int numerator;
    Base(): numerator(666)
    {
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Base& dtostream)
    {
        os << "Base: " << dtostream.numerator << endl;
        return os;
    }
    
};



class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():a(111), ch('x')
    {

    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Derived& x)
    {
        cout << "Derived: ";
        cout << x.a << " " << x.ch << endl;
    }
    char ch;
    int a;
};



int main()
{
    Base* arr = new Derived[5];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Выводиться какая-то ******:

```
Base: 666

Base: -842150536

Base: 111

Base: 666

Base: -842150536
```

Но почему? Что за значения? Почему вызвался оператор << не дочернего класса?

Comment: Потому что то, что вы хотите - динамический полиморфизм - требует виртуальных функций. Чего у вас никак нет.

Сейчас попробую набросать, как надо...

Comment: Просил бы также вас избегать обсценной лексики. Тут бывают женщины и дети :)

Comment: для массивов так не работает. И если немного подумать (размер класса), то сразу станет все понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что то, что вы хотите - динамический полиморфизм - требует виртуальных функций. Чего у вас никак нет.

Хотите динамического полиморфизма - обеспечьте его, например:

```
class Base
{
public:
    int numerator;
    Base(): numerator(666)
    {
    }
    virtual ostream& out(ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << "Base: " << numerator << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived():a(111), ch('x')
    {

    }
    char ch;
    int a;
    virtual ostream& out(ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << "Derived: " << a << "  " << ch << endl;
    }
};



ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Base& b)
{
    return b.out(os);
}


int main()
{
    Derived * arr = new Derived[5];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Замечу также, что, поскольку `sizeof(Base)` и `sizeof(Derived)` не равны, ваша попытка

```
Base* arr = new Derived[5];
```

конечно, смелая, но... но `arr[1]` и далее - совсем не указатели на элементы `Derived`, а на какие-то промежуточные места в памяти. Вот и получается [censored]. Подумайте об этом.

Comment: спасибо, за цензуру извиняюсь!